# Python bit flips when writing a file

Tags: python, file, byte

## **Background**

This is a steganography project I am working on. The code is supposed to do the following:

1. Read a mp3 file (in bytes)
2. Find the frame headers (via the frame sync bits 0xFF)
3. Get and convert a secret message (string) into bits
4. Insert the bits into different parts of the frame header, such as bit 24, 29, 30. (with reference to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#/media/File:Mp3filestructure.svg))
5. Write the data back into a new file
6. Try and retrieve the data from this new file

## **Errors encountered**

Currently, after writing back to the file, when trying to retrieve the data from the newly written file, a few parts of the text will become garbled. Upon further analysis, it seems that there were some bit flips that occurred. In the following code, only options for 2 bits have been increasing the number of bits just adds a few more function call per bit. This issue occurs once more than one bit is used.

## **The code**

steg.py:

```
import binascii
import utility


def encode_message(list_of_hex: list, message: str, num_bits: int = 1):
    """Function takes in a list of hexadecimal values in byte format, a message in string format and number of bits
    to replace (defaults to 1). Replaces the bytes in place so there is no return"""
    message_counter = 0
    message = ''.join(f"{ord(i):08b}" for i in message)
    length_of_message = len(message)
    if length_of_message % num_bits != 0:
        message += (num_bits - (length_of_message % num_bits)) * '0'
    for i in range(len(list_of_hex)):
        if message_counter < length_of_message:
            if list_of_hex[i] == b'ff' and list_of_hex[i + 1][:1] == b'f':
                if num_bits == 1:
                    current_byte = utility.convert_byte_hex_to_bin(list_of_hex[i + 2])  # Gets the next 8 bits (17-24)
                    replaced_byte = utility.encode_bit_0(current_byte, message[message_counter])  # Replace bit 24
                    message_counter += 1
                    list_of_hex[i + 2] = utility.convert_bin_to_hex(replaced_byte)
                elif num_bits == 2:
                    current_byte = utility.convert_byte_hex_to_bin(list_of_hex[i + 2])  # Gets the next 8 bits (17-24)
                    replaced_byte = utility.encode_bit_0(current_byte, message[message_counter])  # Replace bit 24
                    message_counter += 1
                    list_of_hex[i + 2] = utility.convert_bin_to_hex(replaced_byte)
                    # Encodes the next part of the header (Bits 25-32).
                    current_byte = utility.convert_byte_hex_to_bin(list_of_hex[i + 3])  # Gets the next 8 bits (25-32)
                    replaced_byte = utility.encode_bit_0(current_byte, message[message_counter])  # Replace bit 32
                    message_counter += 1
                    list_of_hex[i + 3] = utility.convert_bin_to_hex(replaced_byte)
                elif num_bits == 3:
                    ...
                elif num_bits == 4:
                    ...
                elif num_bits == 5:
                    ...
                elif num_bits == 6:  # Expect audio difference from here on out
                    ...
                elif num_bits == 7:  # Expect audio difference from here on out
                    ...
        else:
            break


def decode_message(list_of_hex: list, len_message: int, num_bits: int = 1):
    """Function takes in a list of hexadecimal values in byte format, length of the message (in terms of
    the number of characters) and number of bits per message (defaults to 1).
     Returns a list of binary values (1's and 0's)"""
    binary_list = []
    current_len = 0
    for i in range(len(list_of_hex)):
        if list_of_hex[i] == b'ff' and list_of_hex[i + 1][:1] == b'f':
            if current_len < len_message * 8:
                if num_bits == 1:
                    current_byte = utility.convert_byte_hex_to_bin(list_of_hex[i + 2])  # Gets the next 8 bits (17-24)
                    binary_list.append(current_byte[-1])  # inserts bit 24 into list
                    current_len += 1
                elif num_bits == 2:
                    current_byte = utility.convert_byte_hex_to_bin(list_of_hex[i + 2])  # Gets the next 8 bits (17-24)
                    binary_list.append(current_byte[-1])  # inserts bit 24 into list
                    current_len += 1
                    current_byte = utility.convert_byte_hex_to_bin(list_of_hex[i + 3])  # Gets the next 8 bits (25-32)
                    binary_list.append(current_byte[-1])  # inserts bit 32 into list
                    current_len += 1
                elif num_bits == 3:
                    ...
                elif num_bits == 4:
                    ...
                elif num_bits == 5:
                    ...
                elif num_bits == 6:
                    ...
                elif num_bits == 7:
                    ...
            else:
                break
    return binary_list

def text_from_bits(bits, encoding='utf8', errors='surrogatepass'):
    """Function takes in a string of bits.
    Parameters that can be overriden: Encoding and errors
    Returns text from a list of binary values (1's and 0's)"""
    n = int(bits, 2)
    return n.to_bytes((n.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big').decode(encoding, errors) or '\0'


def write_secret_to_file(filename: str, secret: str, num_bits: int = 1):
    """Function takes in the filename of mp3 file, secret to be encoded inside and number of bits to use.
    Writes the secret message into a new file called secret.mp3 which is created in the same directory"""

    encodelist = utility.read_file_into_hex_list(filename)
    encode_message(encodelist, secret, num_bits)
    with open('secret.mp3', 'wb') as filewrite:
        filewrite.write(binascii.unhexlify(b''.join(encodelist)))


def get_secret_from_file(filename: str, msg_len: int, num_bits: int = 1):
    """Function takes in the filename of the mp3 file which has a secret inside, the length of the secret message
    (in number of characters) and number of bits to use. Returns the decoded secret"""

    decodelist = utility.read_file_into_hex_list(filename)
    decoded_byte = decode_message(decodelist, msg_len, num_bits)
    decoded_byte_list = [decoded_byte[i:i + 8] for i in range(0, len(decoded_byte), 8)]
    char_list = []
    for i in decoded_byte_list:
        try:
            char_list.append(text_from_bits(''.join(i)))
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            break
    return ''.join(char_list)
```

utility.py:

```
import binascii


def encode_bit_0(bin_str: str, bit: str):
    """Function takes in the byte (in terms of binary) to manipulate and a bit to encode (1 or 0). Changes bit 0.
     Returns the encoded value as a string """
    replaced_byte = bin_str[:-1] + bit  # Replaces bit 0 aka LSB
    return replaced_byte  # padding to ensure 2 digits


def encode_bit_1(bin_str: str, bit: str):
    """Function takes in the byte (in terms of binary) to manipulate and a bit to encode (1 or 0). Changes bit 1.
     Returns the encoded value as a string """
    replaced_byte = bin_str[:-2] + bit + bin_str[-1]  # Encodes bit 1
    return replaced_byte

...

def convert_bin_to_hex(bin_str: str):
    """Takes in a binary string (string of 1's and 0's) and formats it into the hexadecimal value"""
    return bytes(f'{int(bin_str, 2):x}', 'utf8').zfill(2)  # padding to ensure 2 digits


def convert_byte_hex_to_bin(hex_str: bytes):
    """Takes in a hex string in byte form and formats it into a binary string"""
    return bin(int(hex_str, 16))[2:].zfill(8)


def read_file_into_hex_list(file: str):
    with open(file, 'rb') as fileread:
        file_hex_str = binascii.hexlify(fileread.read())

    return [file_hex_str[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(file_hex_str), 2)]
```

main.py

```
import steg

num_bits = 1
msg = 'Test'

steg.write_secret_to_file('audio.mpeg', msg, num_bits)

print(steg.get_secret_from_file('secret.mp3', len(msg), num_bits))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using `binascii` library is unnecessary and seems to overly complicate things.

On the mp3 I used `b'\xff\xfb' seemed good way to search for the header.

I used a list of booleans to store the values of the characters to be hidden in the file.

Here is the way I solved the problem:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import re
from typing import List, Tuple

sync_word = b'\xff\xfb'


def max_msg_len(data: bytes) -> int:
    header_count = data.count(sync_word)
    return (header_count * 3) // 8


def get_header_locations(data: bytes) -> List[int]:
    result = [_.start() for _ in re.finditer(sync_word, data)]
    return result


def text_to_bits(txt: str) -> List[bool]:
    data = txt.encode()
    bin_str = ''.join([f"{x:08b}" for x in data])
    bits = [x == '1' for x in bin_str]
    return bits


def bits_to_text(bits: List[bool]) -> bytearray:
    data = bytearray()
    for x in range(0, (len(bits) // 8 * 8), 8):
        char = int(''.join(['1' if i else '0' for i in bits[x:x+8]]), 2)
        data.append(char)
    return data


def show_header(header: bytes) -> None:
    bin_str = ''.join([f"{x:08b}" for x in header])
    print("Show header:", bin_str)


def show_bits(header: bytes) -> None:
    sig_bits = extract_bits(header)
    print("Hidden bits", sig_bits)


def extract_bits(header: bytes) -> Tuple[bool, bool, bool]:
    bit_24 = get_bit(header[2], 0)  # 24
    bit_29 = get_bit(header[3], 3)  # 29
    bit_30 = get_bit(header[3], 2)  # 30
    return bit_24, bit_29, bit_30


def read_file(filename: Path) -> bytes:
    return filename.read_bytes()


def write_file(filename: Path, data: bytes) -> None:
    filename.write_bytes(data)


def extract_message(data: bytes) -> str:
    header_locs = get_header_locations(data)
    extracted_bits = []
    for idx in header_locs:
        header = data[idx:idx + 4]
        found_bits = extract_bits(header)
        extracted_bits.extend(found_bits)
    words = bits_to_text(extracted_bits)
    return_str = ''.join([x for x in words.decode() if x.isprintable()])
    return return_str


def write_message(data: bytes, bits: List[bool]) -> bytes:
    data = bytearray(data)
    header_locs = get_header_locations(data)
    header_pointer = 0
    for bit_pos, bit_val in enumerate(bits):
        header_pos = bit_pos % 3
        idx = header_locs[header_pointer]
        header = data[idx:idx + 4]
        if header_pos == 0:
            header[2] = set_bit(header[2], 0, bit_val)  # 24
        elif header_pos == 1:
            header[3] = set_bit(header[3], 3, bit_val)  # 29
        elif header_pos == 2:
            header[3] = set_bit(header[3], 2, bit_val)  # 30
            header_pointer += 1
        data[idx:idx + 4] = header
    return data


def set_bit(word, bit, value):
    mask = 1 << bit
    word &= ~mask
    if value:
        word |= mask
    return word


def get_bit(word, bit):
    value = word >> bit
    value &= 1
    return value


def main(mp3_in: Path, mp3_out: Path, msg: str) -> None:
    print('Message to hide:', msg)
    result = text_to_bits(msg)
    # Read mp3 file
    mp3_content = read_file(mp3_in)
    # Check message will fit in mp3 file
    if len(msg) > max_msg_len(mp3_content):
        print(f"Message too long for mp3 file. "
              f"Can only have {max_msg_len(mp3_content)} characters")
        exit()
    # Modify data
    new_data = write_message(mp3_content, result)
    # Check message can be extracted
    extracted_msg = extract_message(new_data)
    print("Message in new mp3:", extracted_msg)
    # Save to file
    write_file(mp3_out, new_data)
    # Read from secret file
    mp3_content = read_file(mp3_out)
    extracted_msg = extract_message(mp3_content)
    print(f"From {mp3_out.name} read: {extracted_msg}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Files
    original_mp3 = Path.home().joinpath('Desktop', 'warning.mp3')
    secret_mp3 = Path.home().joinpath('Desktop', 'secret.mp3')
    # Message
    txt_to_hide = 'short test message'
    main(original_mp3, secret_mp3, txt_to_hide)
```

Which gave the following output:

```
Message to hide: short test message
Message in new mp3: short test message
From secret.mp3 read: short test message
```

Comment: +1, it makes sense. However, I still have not figured out why my own code does not work. I have changed it such that it now does not touch bit 24 and it works fine.